# How to load ICC profile from classpath?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, pdfa, color-profile, color-management

While trying to generate PDF that conforms to PDF/A standard using Jasper Reports, I got

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRPdfaIccProfileNotFoundException.
```

This is easily fixed by configuring

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdfa.icc.profile.path" value="/stuff/myicc.icc"/>
```

but I need to bundle the icc profile with rest of the WAR just like the fonts the report embeds. How can this be done? I'm looking something like

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdfa.icc.profile.path" value="classpath:/jasper/someicc.icc"/>
```

But this did not work, nor did icc profile relative to the report itself. Can I pass the InputStream as a parameter to the PDFGenerator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up creating our own extension to handle classpath loading to make it more centralized.

The code to implement classpath extension is here:

```
package com.somepackage;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRPropertiesMap;
import net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.ExtensionsRegistry;
import net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.ExtensionsRegistryFactory;
import net.sf.jasperreports.repo.InputStreamResource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryService;
import net.sf.jasperreports.repo.Resource;

/**
 * JasperReports extension factory that enables to read from classpath. Only tries to resolve URLs that start with "classpath:".
 */
public class ClasspathExtensionsRegistryFactory implements ExtensionsRegistryFactory {

    @Override
    public ExtensionsRegistry createRegistry(String registryId, JRPropertiesMap properties) {
        return extFactory;
    }

    private static final ClasspathRepositoryService service = new ClasspathRepositoryService();
    private static final List<ClasspathRepositoryService> services = Collections.singletonList(service);
    private static final ExtensionsRegistry extFactory = new ExtensionsRegistry() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public <T> List<T> getExtensions(Class<T> extensionType) {
                        if (RepositoryService.class.equals(extensionType)) {
                            return (List<T>) services;
                        }
                        return null;
                }
    };

    /**
     * RepositoryService that reads resources from classpath.
     */
    public static class ClasspathRepositoryService implements RepositoryService {

        private static final String CLASSPATH_PREFIX = "classpath:";
        private static final int CLASSPATH_PREFIX_LENGTH = CLASSPATH_PREFIX.length();

        @Override
        public Resource getResource(String uri) {
            return getResource(uri, InputStreamResource.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void saveResource(String uri, Resource resource) {
            //No-op
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public <K extends Resource> K getResource(String uri, Class<K> resourceType) {
            if (resourceType != null && InputStreamResource.class.equals(resourceType) && uri != null && uri.trim().startsWith(CLASSPATH_PREFIX)) {
                InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(uri.trim().substring(CLASSPATH_PREFIX_LENGTH));
                if (is != null) {
                    InputStreamResource isr = new InputStreamResource();
                    isr.setInputStream(is);
                    isr.setName(uri);
                    return (K)isr;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

After that the only thing left to do is to add jasperreports_extension.properties file that contains
    net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.classpathresourcereader=com.somepackage.ClasspathExtensionsRegistryFactory

This enables one to conf the exporter like this:

```
SimplePdfExporterConfiguration pec = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
.
.
.
pec.setIccProfilePath("classpath:/somefolder/iccprofile.icc");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are exporting from java code you can use the [`getClassLoader().getResource()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) to get the absolute path to file.

**Example with JRPdfExporter**

```
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
//... your input and output
SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
URL path = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("jasper/someicc.icc");
configuration.setIccProfilePath(path.getFile());
//other settings
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
exporter.exportReport();
```